# Need to draw a realtime chart ( like ECG) using C# if it is possible ( for mobile phones)

Tags: c#, xamarin, graph, graphics, skiasharp

My app recieve realtime data from ECG monitor and it should draw twelve graphs on a tablet/phone.
I already try to use SkiaSharp for this and Xamarin, but there is a real problem with drawing recieved data, the delay is to high since i dont understand how to clear the graph that is hidden behind the screen. 
Maybe someone know how to clear hidden parts, or can suggest another solution,like different framework or library.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls (DATA VISUALIZATION) its free for small companies and private projects.